# How use distinct inside joint query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have found how to remove duplicates using distinct in mysql, but its not working on my inner join query,

Btw this is inside a php file. My problem is I cannot remove the duplicates using distinct cause I have no idea how to use distinct in a inner join query.

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT student.username, student.f_name,student.m_name,student.l_name, student.course, result.q_id, result.correct FROM student INNER JOIN result ON student.id=result.stud_id WHERE s_group='$me'") or die ("no records found!");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
  {
    $pdf->Cell(26,9,$row['username'],1,0);
    $pdf->Cell(30,9,$row['f_name'],1,0);
    $pdf->Cell(30,9,$row['m_name'],1,0);
    $pdf->Cell(30,9,$row['l_name'],1,0);
    $pdf->Cell(30,9,$row['course'],1,0);
    $pdf->Cell(29,9,$row['q_id'],1,1);
  }
}
```

Comment: use mysql **group by**

Comment: DISTINCT how? SELECT DISTINCT will return distinct rows. But if you want for example distinct student.username (or other), you need to decide how to chose the other values (when different.)

Comment: what do i need to use if i want no duplicates on username?

Comment: @YEYE `GROUP BY username`

Comment: If a student has done several classes, what's the expected result?

Comment: it works ! thank you sir Alex , i guess my title is wrong? hehe

Comment: `distinct` applies to the ENTIRE row, not just whatever field you slap  the distinct keyword on. it's basically `select distinct(field1, field2, ...) from`, not `select distinct(field1), field2, .... from`

Comment: yah, i guess im wrong on using distinct, anyways thank you for helping me

Comment: I think you want a formatted output, where the user's data is displayed only once, while the course related data are repeated. If you want this, then format the output, do not try to achive this in your query.